# xcode 4.6 Target Build Setting missing the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ... " sections

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

In xcode 4.6, I created a new project with multiple targets.  One of my targets, an empty iOS application, is missing all of the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections from the Target Build Settings. Anyone else seen this?  Any idea on how to get them to display?

I am able to replicate the situation consistently in six steps:

1. Start xcode 4.6
2. File --> New --> Project...
3. Select an OS X Framework & Library --> Bundle (accept all defaults)
4. In that project, File --> New --> Target...
5. Select an iOS Application --> Empty Application (accept all defaults)
6. Goto the iOS Application target's "Build Settings", notice no "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections

**With "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections**
[image: With "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections]

**Without "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections**
[image]

Comment: Hi mmorris,did you find any solution to this issue.I ran in to the same broblem when i need to enable ARC for framework target in x-code4.6.Please help me if you have some solution with you.

Comment: @Hariprasad I was able to resolve the particular issue using the method below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I created a new project with an initial target that was an OS X Bundle (see step 3 on how to replicate the situation in the question), the default setting for all added targets inherit the projects settings which in this case were for OS X.  When I added and iOS Empty Application target, the "Build Settings" were correct, but the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections were missing.

I was able to get the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections in the "Build Settings" to display for the iOS Empty Application target by changing the **Project**'s *(not any of the Targets')* "Build Settings" "Architectures" section in the following manor:

`Base SDK` from: `Latest OS X (OS X 10.8)` to: `Latest iOS (iOS 6.1)`

`Architectures` from: `64-bit Intel` to: `Standard (armv7, armv7s)`

Then click on the iOS Empty Application target's Build Settings" and there are the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections.

Comment: hmmm i too am missing those APPLE LLVM build settings and when i look at my prject build setting, they are already set to what you are saying to change them to...

Comment: @towpse Make sure you pay attention to the distinction between **project** and **target** "Build Settings".  Mismatched **project** and **target** "Build Settings" where the **target** is iOS target resulted in missing "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections.  If both the **project** and **target** "Build Settings" match, then you found an other fun _"feature"_ of xcode.

Comment: This is something that should be filed as a radar.

Comment: I've followed the same... But unable to get "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ..." sections... :(

Comment: @Raj see my response to towpse. You also may have a completely different issue.  Kinda of funny that you would down vote for that.

Comment: I am having this issue in Xcode 5.1.1 but this solution did not resolve it for me.