# Over 1000 compiler errors after updating to Xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently updated from XCode 4.5 to XCode 4.6. I had an iOS project that compiled with no errors in 4.5, but now, when I build the project in 4.6, I get over 1000 errors.

The errors include `"expected property type before 'strong'` in my `@property (nonatomic, strong)` declarations, and every time I reference object properties as `self.propertyName` I get the error `request for member propertyName not found in structure of union`

That makes me think it has something to do with ARC or the compiler, but I'm not sure sure what I would change. I checked that the project is using LLVM GCC 4.2

Comment: Look in the build setting of the target and make sure ARC is still enabled.

Comment: in the user defined section, `CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC` is set to `YES`

Comment: It's over NINE THOUSAND!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC is only supported by the LLVM Compiler (v3.0 or higher). It is not supported by LLVM GCC 4.2 or GCC 4.2. Switch your project to using the LLVM Compiler (aka Clang) and these problems will go away.

Comment: thanks, that fixes a lot, but for some reason I can only choose LLVM 1.7. Do you know why the later versions of LLVM aren't displaying?

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967836/xcode-4-6-target-build-setting-missing-the-apple-llvm-compiler-4-2-sect, but the highest base sdk I can choose is iOS 4.3

Comment: What value are available to you in the pop-up for the "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" build setting of your project?

Comment: GCC 4.0, GCC 4.2, LLVM GCC 4.2, LLVM 1.7 - and if it's relevant, it just says C/C++, not C/C++/Objective-C

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using Xcode 4.6. GCC 4.0 only comes with old versions of Xcode. Check the Xcode version number in Xcode -> About Xcode to see which version you're actually running.

Comment: That was the problem. For some reason I opened 3.2.6. Thanks again