# Xcode can't find LLVM preprocessor

Tags: ios, xcode, preprocessor, llvm

Hello I create a new target (Aggregation) and I need to set some preprocessor variables but I can't find LLVM preprocessing!!

I searched and found this:
[xcode 4.6 Target Build Setting missing the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - ... " sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967836/xcode-4-6-target-build-setting-missing-the-apple-llvm-compiler-4-2-sect)

but did not work me!

Any help with it

Comment: What does "Aggregation" mean in this context?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am building framework so aggregate is needed to me you can say to select target dependency